# Return entities that do NOT exist in JPA

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm using Spring Boot and MySQL.
I have a Book database entity and I'm receiving a list of books from a controller.
How can I filter that list of books for entities that do NOT exist in the database.

So if the database contains books `[1, 2, 3]` and I'm receiving books `[3, 4, 5]`, then I would like to only filter books `[4, 5]`.

Comment: Parse your input JSON array to separate rows, a book per row, test each of them for the absence in contained books JSON array and select only non-existent ones, combine them back to JSON array.

Comment: @Akina Just out of curiosity, if the db has far more records that the input JSON array, wouldn't it be more efficient to check the db if each individual book input exists (3 queries if input has 3 books), rather than using 1 Query (which might select far more books than 3) ?

Comment: @don Of course backward variant is possible too. But OP shows that both existing and received lists are single arrays, not many arrays each...

Answer (score 0):

How about selecting the ones that exist and then filtering them out.

e.g.

```
// GIVEN
DB= [1, 2, 3, 4]

// WHEN
Request= [3,4,6,7]

// THEN
Fetch books that exist [3,4]
Remove existing books from the request [6,7]
```

Doing so makes you send only one query to the DB!